# I want to associate my website with my app, just like with Youtube, or Twitter app

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created a WebView app for my website.I want to associate my website links to my app, such that if a user gets any link of my website, it prompts the user to open that link in app(if installed) or in browser. Just like with the Youtube app, or Twitter app.

Comment: try firebase deep links

Comment: Firebase deeplink will force user to download the app from play store..

Comment: yes if the app is not installed

Comment: I do not want to force users to download the app first. If they have app installed, let the link open in app, otherwise open the link in browser itself.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking